# DeleteDuplicates

Tags: list-manipulation, interpolation

After having applied "DeleteDuplicates" to a list of data (15000 rows per 3 columns), when I try to interpolate that list of data it gives me back again: 
"There are duplicated abscissa points in.."

Could anyone help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: Take a look: `Interpolation@DeleteDuplicates[{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}}]` and compare with `DeleteDuplicatesBy[{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}}, Most]`. Additional question is, how do you want to handle multiple values in one point.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But now, when I try to interpolate it give me back: 

"The element mesh has insufficient quality of -6.58881*10^-11. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements."

Do you kindly know hot to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Minimal example + code or nothing happened.

Comment: Take a look also at `Interpolation@ DeleteDuplicates[{{1., 1.}, {1. + $MachineEpsilon, 1. + 2 $MachineEpsilon}, {2., 4.}}, Most]` and compare with `Interpolation@ DeleteDuplicates[{{1., 1.}, {1. + $MachineEpsilon, 1. + 2 $MachineEpsilon}, {2., 4.}}, Most[#1] == Most[#2] &]`.